# Can't browse to www folder from some programs

Tags: permissions

I have apache setup so I can develop websites locally from /var/www I can browse the this folder perfectly fine from some programs such as Nautilus and Atom but can't from others such as Gitkraken (I get a permission denied message).

I get that this is do do with permissions but don't know which it affects some programs and not others. Most have been installed through the software center in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I have found uninstalling Gitkraken via snap and downloading it from the website and re-installing it that way has worked. Presumably snap ads extra restrictions.